# Loop overlaps images

Tags: javascript, image, css-float, alignment

I'm a newbie in JavaScript. I have a function that is supposed to loop the same image and text 26 times. and display them like multiple paragraphs of image and text. My loop however is overlapping the text and the image as shown below. [image: format I do not want]

I want my code to display the image as shown below.[image: format I want to display.]

How can I fix this? my JavaScript code looks like this

```
function getData() {
  var stringData = '';

  for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    stringData = stringData + '<div><image src="img/sample-image.png" width="10% "height="10%" align="left" border="0"/>' + 'In this example a sample of the album photo on the site shall appear alongside a simple description of the album. To view the album select the album.</div><br/>';
  }

  document.getElementById("list-menu").innerHTML = '' + stringData + '';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply adding in [two `<br />`s should do the trick.](http://jsfiddle.net/WmneH/), other than that, try [`clear: both` in your div CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/WmneH/1/).

Comment: This occurs because your images are being 'aligned left'. The `align="left"` attribute is treated just like a `float: left;` statement in css. Whenever children are floated inside a parent, the parent collapses - pretty much taking it out of the document. This is the reason why all your floated images interact with one another. The best ways to get the parent to reassert itself are (1) to use `clear: both;` as Daedalus states *(this clears any floating affects around the parent)* or (2) `overflow: hidden;` *(which forces the parent to calculate it's height correctly and wrap it's children.)*